# Определить наличие метода в конкретном классе при наследовании

Tags: php, ооп

Вопрос к гуру PHP, есть у меня конструкция из нескольких классов:

```
class A {

}

class B extends A {
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }
}

class C extends B {
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }
}

$c = new C();
```

Как сделать такой метод класса C, который бы определял наличие или отсутствие метода с заданным именем только внутри класса C, игнорируя классы A и B (нюанс в том, что на самом деле этих классов больше чем 2). В идеале ещё определять тип метода: public, private, protected.

Comment: через `ReflectionClass` и `ReflectionMethod`, но, говорят, медленно. а можно просто проверить наличие метода в родительском классе, но тут без видимости.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, как вариант, создать в классе метод:

```
  public function hasMethod($m)
  {
      $child = new ReflectionClass(get_class($this));
      $parent = $child->getParentClass();

      if ($child->hasMethod($m)) {
          if ($parent->hasMethod($m)) {
              try {
                  if ($child->getMethod($m)->getPrototype()) {
                      return true;
                  }
              } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
                return false;
              }
          }
          return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
```

Comment: У меня была примерно такая же идея, только общий список методов я получал через get_class_methods. Но есть другая проблема. А если метод переопределяется в классе C? Он в этом случае будет считаться как отсутствующий в нём. Не комильфо в общем...

Comment: Изменил пример, сейчас отрабатывает правильно

Comment: Спасибо! Вы очень помогли!